# LINQ - get parent of parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using EntityFramework 6, code-first and have a hierarchy like that:

a **ProductCategory** 
    => has many **Products** 
        => where one Product has many **ProductDetails**.

Another entity "SalesOrderDetail" has one property "ProductDetail". What I am looking for is a linq query which gets all SalesOrderDetails which belong to one ProductCategory.

TIA
Heiko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
IEnumerable<SalesOrderDetail> result = orderDetails.Where(order => order.ProductDetail.Product.ProductCategory.Id == searchedProductCategoryId);
```

Comment: Life can be so easy... sometimes. :-)